# Django project deployed on aws ec2 not loading after ssl configuration

Tags: django, nginx, amazon-ec2

I have deployed my django website on ec2 instance with custom domain. Everything was working until i configured ssl then the site would load for very long time and return "This site can’t be reached".

Here is my my nginx file:

```
server{
    server_name example.com;


    location / {

            include proxy_params;
            proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/lsh_bank/app.sock;

    }


listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
server{
if ($host = example.com) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
} 



    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

Answer (score 0):

"This site can’t be reached" error is showing because you didn't given your domain name or IP. instead of example.com as you given, you need to change them into your publicIps. as you were using aws, your IP will be given in the bottom of the connect in the aws console or in the instance there will be Private IPv4 addresses.